# run button's click on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a input like this "

```
<input type='button' name='osx' value='Demo' class='osx demo' runat="server" />
```

that when i click on this , it runs a jQuery plugin.
now i want to call this input's click event on my page load, in fact i want to run it's plugin at page load, so i use this code :

```
<script>
    $("document").ready(function () {
        window.getElementById("osx").click();
    });
</script>
```

but when i run my page , i get this error :

> Line: 16
>   Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementById'

### can enyone help me ,please?

i done all of your answers but non of them worked for me!!!
here in my page's code :

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link type='text/css' href='css/osx.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
    <script>
       $("document").ready(function () {
   document.getElementById("osx").click();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id='content'>
            <div id='osx-modal'>
                <input id='osx' type='button' name='osx' value='Demo' class='osx demo' runat="server" />
                or <a href='#' class='osx'>Demo</a>
            </div>
            <!-- modal content -->
            <div id="osx-modal-content">
                <div id="osx-modal-title" dir="rtl">
                    OSX Style Modal Dialog</div>
                <div class="close">
                    <a href="#" class="simplemodal-close">x</a></div>
                <div id="osx-modal-data">
                    <h2>
                        Hello! I'm SimpleModal!</h2>
                    <p>
                        SimpleModal is a lightweight jQuery Plugin which provides a powerful interface for
                        modal dialog development. Think of it as a modal dialog framework.</p>
                    <p>
                        SimpleModal gives you the flexibility to build whatever you can envision, while
                        shielding you from related cross-browser issues inherent with UI development..</p>
                    <p>
                        As you can see by this example, SimpleModal can be easily configured to behave like
                        an OSX dialog. With a handful options, 2 custom callbacks and some styling, you
                        have a visually appealing dialog that is ready to use!</p>
                    <p>
                        <button class="simplemodal-close">
                            Close</button>
                        <span>(or press ESC or click the overlay)</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/osx.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

where am i do wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   document.getElementById("osx").click();
});
</script>
```

or

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('osx').click();">
```

with id="osx" added to your input element

Comment: i get same error again : "Line: 16
Error: Unable to get property 'click' of undefined or null referen"

Comment: have you added the id attribute to input tag?

Comment: first part is not correct because you were using `$("document")` which should not have quotes.

Answer (score 5):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name=osx]").click();
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rNGgm/

OR Without jQuery

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
        document.getElementById("osx").click();
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rNGgm/1/

Comment: i got thi error again : "Line: 12
Error: Unable to get property 'click' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: remove quotes in `$("document")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("<%=btnProvideContactInfo.ClientID%>").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why it did not work for you**

`getElementById` is not a method of window object. It is a method of `document` object, so use `document.getElementById("osx").click();` and your `input` tag should have `id='osx'`.

you were using `$("document")`. Dont put quotes around `document` in `$(document)`.

**How to solve it**

Add `id` attribute to your input element -

```
<input id='osx' type='button' name='osx' value='Demo' class='osx demo' runat="server" />
```

And if you like to use jQuery, then -

```
 $(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#osx").click();//using id selector
 }
```

otherwise using `document.getElementById`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   document.getElementById("osx").click();
}
```

Comment: you were using `$("document")`. Dont put quotes around `document` in `$(document)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.trigger()` like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $(".osx").trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

And you didnt have the `id` atribute.So add it and try

```
<input type='button' name='osx' value='Demo' class='osx demo' id='osx' runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "trigger":

```
 <script>
     $(function () {
         $(".osx").trigger("click");
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: i use that but nothing happened

Comment: Strange. What does the console say?

Answer (score 0):

use jQuerys .trigger()

```
<input type='button' id='osx' value='Demo' class='osx demo' runat="server" />
```

this is jQuery code..

```
<script>
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $('#osx').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you place id in input type.

```
<input type='button' name='osx' value='Demo' class='osx demo' id='osx' runat="server" />
```